# Animate elements in ListView on initialization

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-animatedlist

I want to achieve something like below (animation style doesn't matter, I'm looking for *the way* to do this)

[image: example]

However, all resources and question only explain how to create
item addition or removal animations.

My current code (I use BLoC pattern)

```
class _MembersPageState extends State<MembersPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<MembersPageBloc>(
      create: (context) =>
          MembersPageBloc(userRepository: UserRepository.instance)..add(MembersPageShowed()),
      child: BlocBuilder<MembersPageBloc, MembersPageState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is MembersPageSuccess) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: state.users.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                User user = state.users[index];

                return ListTile(
                  isThreeLine: true,
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person, size: 36),
                  title: Text(user.name),
                  subtitle: Text(user.username),
                  onTap: () => null,
                );
              },
            );
          } else
            return Text("I don't care");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100219/how-to-animate-the-items-rendered-initially-using-animated-list-in-flutter

Answer (score 7):

Widgets like `AnimatedOpacity` and `AnimatedPositioned` can be used to achieve this. However, lifecycle of the children widgets in a `ListView` is a bit complex. They get destroyed and recreated according to the scroll position. If the child widget has an animation that starts on initialization, it will reanimate whenever the child gets visible to the UI.

Here is my *hacky* solution. I used a static boolean to indicate whether it's the "first time" or "recreation" state and simply ignore the "recreation". You can copy and try it in Dartpad.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
        body: ListView(
          children: List.generate(
            25,
            (i) => AnimatedListItem(i, key: ValueKey<int>(i)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;

  const AnimatedListItem(this.index, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnimatedListItem> createState() => _AnimatedListItemState();
}

class _AnimatedListItemState extends State<AnimatedListItem> {
  bool _animate = false;

  static bool _isStart = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (_isStart) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: widget.index * 100), () {
        setState(() {
          _animate = true;
          _isStart = false;
        });
      });
    } else {
      _animate = true;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedOpacity(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      opacity: _animate ? 1 : 0,
      curve: Curves.easeInOutQuart,
      child: AnimatedPadding(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
        padding: _animate
            ? const EdgeInsets.all(4.0)
            : const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        child: Container(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(height: 100),
          child: Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                widget.index.toString(),
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I'm not adding nor removing items. I already have some items I receive from backend. All I want to do is to create "laying out" animation for those.

Comment: Well, I have to say it creates serious problems with scrolling when there are more items. I'll keep this accepted, but it doesn't work well.

Comment: I will update my answer so that it will animate only on start. You can also add that logic by yourself too. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: How to achieve the "slide from bottom" effect from the gif above with this approach. Thanks.

Comment: how about https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I created a [gist](https://dartpad.dev/0fc3ae4255fb66367b127299c454d274) on dartpad shows how to add initial animation for `ListView`

The key point is to create an `AnimationController` for each list item, cache it, and clean up when animation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DifferentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DifferentPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DifferentPage> createState() => DifferentStatePage();
}

class DifferentStatePage extends State<DifferentPage> {
  final _item = [];
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _key = GlobalKey();

  void _addItem() {
    _item.insert(0, 'Item ${_item.length + 1}');
    _key.currentState!.insertItem( 0,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
  }

 void _removeItem(int index) {
   _key.currentState!.removeItem( index, (_, animation) {
     return SizeTransition(
       sizeFactor: animation,
       child: const Card(
         margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
         color: Colors.red,
         child: ListTile(
           title: Text(
             'Deleted',
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
           ),
         ),
       ),
     );
   },
   duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
 );
   _item.removeAt(index);
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Column(
     children: [
       const SizedBox( height: 10 ),
     IconButton(
       onPressed: _addItem,
       icon: const Icon(Icons.add_box_rounded),
     ),
     Expanded(
       child: AnimatedList(
         key: _key,
         initialItemCount: 0,
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
         itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
           return SizeTransition(
             key: UniqueKey(),
             sizeFactor: animation,
             child: Card(
               margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
               color: Colors.amberAccent,
               child: ListTile(
                 title: Text(
                   _item[index],
                   style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                 ),
                 trailing: IconButton(
                   icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                   onPressed: () {
                     _removeItem(index);
                   },
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           );
         },
       ),
     )
   ],
 );
 }}
```